# How to resample/upscale or regrid netcdf file? In order to compare and make some calculation

Tags: netcdf

I have a dataset from MEaSUREs Calibrated Enhanced-Resolution Passive Microwave Daily with different resolutions - N3.125km and N6.25km.
And to make some calculations with the variables I need to resample/upscale data set from N3.125km to N6.25km. How to do it? I'm totally new in Python, please help

Answer (score 0):

One option is my package nctoolkit. Read about it  [here](https://nctoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

If you want to go from 3.125 to 6.25 km, you can use the `resample_grid` method and then select every other cell, as follows:

```
import nctoolkit as nc
ds = nc.open_data("infile.nc")
ds.resample_grid(2)
ds.plot()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [CDO](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/boards/1/topics/2040) for this.

```
cdo griddes infile.nc > targetgrid.nc
cdo setgrid,targetgrid.nc infile.nc outfile.nc
```